# Prove: $\log_2(x)+\log_3(x)+\log_5(x)>9\log_{30}(x)$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, logarithms, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Prove for all $x>1$
>
> $\log_2(x)+\log_3(x)+\log_5(x)>9\log_{30}(x)$

So what I did was:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(5)}>9\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(30)}
\\[6px]
&\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(5)}>9\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2\cdot3\cdot5)}=9\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)+\ln(3)+\ln(5)}
\\[6px]
&\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(5)}\ge3\frac{3\ln(x)}{\sqrt[3]{\ln(2)\ln(3)\ln(5)}}
\\[6px]
&\!\ln(2)+\ln(3)+\ln(5)\ge3\sqrt[3]{\ln(2)\ln(3)\ln(5)}
\\[6px]
&\frac{3\ln(x)}{\sqrt[3]{\ln(2)\ln(3)\ln(5)}}>9\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)+\ln(3)+\ln(5)}
\end{align}

I think this should prove the inequality but I'm not really sure how to formulate it properly if it was in an exam, any tips how to conclude? (if my proof is correct)

Comment: Your proof is upside down, as you should start with something you know to be true, such as the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, and conclude with what you are trying to prove.  You should also probably use $x \gt 1 \implies \ln(x) >0$ in your proof

Comment: Probably write the symbol for the biconditional
$$\iff$$
in-between lines, to indicate that the logical flow goes both ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the left hand side:

$$\log_2{x}+\log_3{x}+\log_5{x} = \frac{\log_{30}{x}}{\log_{30}{2}}+\frac{\log_{30}{x}}{\log_{30}{3}}+\frac{\log_{30}{x}}{\log_{30}{5}}.$$

Factor out $\log_{30}{x}$:

$$\log_2{x}+\log_3{x}+\log_5{x} = \log_{30}x\left(\frac{1}{\log_{30}{2}}+\frac{1}{\log_{30}{5}}+\frac{1}{\log_{30}{5}}\right).$$

Now use the fact that $\frac{1}{\log_b{a}} = \log_a{b}$:

$$\log_2{x}+\log_3{x}+\log_5{x} = \log_{30}{x}\left(\log_2{30}+\log_3{30}+\log_5{30}\right).$$

So now all we need to show is

$$\log_2{30}+\log_3{30}+\log_5{30}>9.$$

$\log_2{16}=4$, and since $\log_2$ is a strictly increasing function, this means $\log_2{30}>(\log_2{16}=)4$. Applying the same logic to the other two $\log$s, we get that $\log_3{30}>3$ and $\log_5{30}>2$, hence

$$\log_2{30}+\log_3{30}+\log_5{30}>4+3+2=9$$

and we are done

Answer (score 1):

From here since $\ln x>0$

$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 5}>9\frac{\ln x}{\ln 30}\iff \frac{1}{\ln 2}+\frac{1}{\ln 3}+\frac{1}{\ln 5}>\frac{9}{\ln 30}$$

we can conclude, indeed by [**HM-AM inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) we have

$$\frac{3}{\frac{1}{\ln 2}+\frac{1}{\ln 3}+\frac{1}{\ln 5}}<\frac{\ln 2+\ln 3+\ln 5}{3}=\frac{\ln 30}{3}
\implies
\frac{1}{\ln 2}+\frac{1}{\ln 3}+\frac{1}{\ln 5}>\frac9{\ln 30}$$

Comment: Looks very interesting, never heard of a harmonic average before.

1.Is the harmonic average necessarily greater than the arithmetic average and not equal to it?


2.Could you please elaborate a bit more on the last step you did?
I'm not sure how the HM-AM proves it completely.

Comment: @Maxim Harmonic mean is less or equal to AM and equality holds only if the positive terms are equals, for the proof and discussion refer to https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality

Answer (score 0):

$$log_2(x)+log_3(x)+log_5(x)>9log_{30}(x) \iff \frac {log(x)}{log2} + \frac {log(x)}{log3}+\frac {log(x)}{log5} >9 \frac {log(x)}{log30}$$

$$\iff \frac {1}{log2} + \frac {1}{log3}+\frac {1}{log5} >9 \frac {1}{log30}$$

$$\iff \log_2 30  +\log_3 30 + \log_5 30     > \log_2 16  +\log_3 27 + \log_5 25 =4+3+2=   9 $$

Comment: aha but how did you do that last calculation? 
Because in an exam, I won't have a calculator to help me with that..

Comment: @Maxim  OK, check my edit if you do not want to use calculator.